# Lisp list and expression

Tags: list, lisp, expression

Recently, I was reading article "Root Of Lisp" from Paul Graham.I encountered some questions.From the book, it defines expression as two :1.atom;2.list, while list is consisted of zero or many expressions.Then it sayes that a list can be evaluated.Now I hava some problems:

1. Can every list be evaluated?Is every list an expression?
2. If a list can be evaluated, then it may have its first element  as an operator,so an operator is an expression?Is operator atomic or another?
3. The operator `car` returns the first element of a list, if the list can be evaluated, then what will it return , the operator?Can you give me some sample of this to show how to use the returned value?
4. The operator `cdr` returns elements besides the first element as a list,then this returned list can't be evaluated?

I am a freshman for Lisp,I don't know whether I hava explained my problems clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Lisp S-expression (sexp) is either an atom, or a list of sexps.

## 1

All Lisp forms (that is, things that can be evaluated) are sexps, but not all sexps are Lisp forms.

More specifically, a Lisp form is any atom, or a list whose first element is a symbol.

```
(foo 42)       ; valid Lisp form
(undefined 42) ; Lisp form, but invalid because of undefined function
(42 foo)       ; not a Lisp form - numbers aren't symbols
```

## 2

As I just mentioned, the "operator" (first element) of a list-that-is-a-Lisp-form must be a symbol. (A Lisp-1 (e.g. Scheme) allows any Lisp form in the operator position, but *Roots of Lisp* is discussing the original (a Lisp-2), and Common Lisp (a Lisp-2); they restrict the operator position to symbols.)

## 3

Lisp code, before compilation, is Lisp data. **That is important.**

If I said `(car 'foo)`, the program would complain; and rightly so, because `foo` isn't a list.

If I said `(car '(car 'foo))`, the inner list is *not* evaluated (good old quote syntax `'`), and `car` extracts the thing in the operator position - in this case, the symbol `car`. This can be useful when defining macros.

## 4

Depends.

First, imagine I have `foo` defined as a function of two arguments, and `bar` defined as both a variable and a function of one argument. Also remember that, under the hood, your Lisp is probably calling `eval` on whatever you type in.

Now `(eval '(foo bar 42))` is valid, and will invoke `foo` with arguments <the value of `bar`> and `42`. `(eval (cdr '(foo bar 42)))` is also perfectly valid; it is equivalent to `(eval '(bar 42))`, which invokes `bar` with the argument `42`.

If `bar` were not defined as a function, the `cdr` of the second example would still produce a valid Lisp form, but it would be an error to evaluate that form, as `(bar 42)` invokes the function `bar` (there isn't one).

It is useful to talk about *syntax* and *semantics*. Syntactically, any atom, or any list with a symbol in operator position, is valid. Semantically (inside the bounds of the syntax), any atom that is a symbol with no variable definition is an error; so is any list whose first element is a symbol with no function definition.

I hope this answer helps you out.

Comment: Is there any other list which is consist of all data elements?like(123 234),is this legal?It needn't to be evaluated, only save data?I don't learn Lisp before.So I may look it in other language style.

Comment: @ohyeahchenzai `(123 234)` is a perfectly valid list of two values (which can be used as data). However, it is not a Lisp form (it has a number in the operator position), so it cannot be evaluated.